# Find neighbors in a matrix?

Tags: python

Here is a 7x7 matrix:

```
11  21  31  41  51  61  71
12  22  32  42  52  62  72
13  23  33  43  53  63  73
14  24  34  44  54  64  74
15  25  35  45  55  65  75
16  26  36  46  56  66  76
17  27  37  47  57  67  77
```

The numbers `11, 21, 33` … are the values of the positions.
If a radius, the number of row and the number of column are given, how to find the neighbors?

For example, function `neighbors(radius = 1, rowNumber = 3, columnNumber = 3)` should return a matrix:

```
22  32  42
23  33  43
24  34  44
```

`function neighbors(radius = 2, rowNumber = 3, columnNumber = 3)` should return a matrix:

```
11  21  31  41  51
12  22  32  42  52
13  23  33  43  53
14  24  34  44  54
15  25  35  45  55
```

When the neighbor is out of boundary, its value should be 0.
For example, `function neighbors(radius = 2, rowNumber = 1, columnNumber = 1)` should return a matrix

```
0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0
0   0   11  21  31
0   0   12  22  32
0   0   13  23  33
```

I've been thing about this problem for 3 days, but I still can't develop a solution for it.

Comment: what have you tried? is your matrix a `numpy.matrix` or a `list` or file content?

Comment: I'm trying to use a 2d array to solve it, but finding problem when dealing with the position whose neighbors are out of boundary.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It might be hard in other languages but in Python this is quite easy. Here is a function that can do what you asked for:

```
def neighbors(radius, row_number, column_number):
     return [[a[i][j] if  i >= 0 and i < len(a) and j >= 0 and j < len(a[0]) else 0
                for j in range(column_number-1-radius, column_number+radius)]
                    for i in range(row_number-1-radius, row_number+radius)]
```

Here is a 2D list:

```
 a = [[ 11,  21,  31,  41,  51,  61,  71],
      [ 12,  22,  32,  42,  52,  62,  72],
      [ 13,  23,  33,  43,  53,  63,  73],
      [ 14,  24,  34,  44,  54,  64,  74],
      [ 15,  25,  35,  45,  55,  65,  75],
      [ 16,  26,  36,  46,  56,  66,  76],
      [ 17,  27,  37,  47,  57,  67,  77]]
```

See [List comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/functional.html#generator-expressions-and-list-comprehensions).

Updated missing "and" in the solution - pls review

Comment: hmm where is a coming from?

Comment: @Ivonet Has been defined outside the function as the 2D list/Array.

Answer (score 6):

This code taking 2d array(matrix) as an argument and return list of elements with all neighbors.

INPUT:

```
 arr = [['a', 'b', 'c'],
        ['d', 'e', 'f'],
        ['g', 'h', 'k']]
```

OUTPUT:

```
[{'value': 'a', 'neighbors': ['b', 'd']}
 {'value': 'b', 'neighbors': ['c', 'e', 'a']}
 {'value': 'c', 'neighbors': ['f', 'b']}
 {'value': 'd', 'neighbors': ['a', 'e', 'g']}
 {'value': 'e', 'neighbors': ['b', 'f', 'h', 'd']}
 {'value': 'f', 'neighbors': ['c', 'k', 'e']}
 {'value': 'g', 'neighbors': ['d', 'h']}
 {'value': 'h', 'neighbors': ['e', 'k', 'g']}
 {'value': 'k', 'neighbors': ['f', 'h']}]
```

more details here -> [GitHub](https://github.com/MaxRudometkin/2d_array_neighbours/blob/master/array_neighbours.py)

```
def find_neighbours(arr):

    neighbors = []

    for i in range(len(arr)):
        for j, value in enumerate(arr[i]):

            if i == 0 or i == len(arr) - 1 or j == 0 or j == len(arr[i]) - 1:
                # corners
                new_neighbors = []
                if i != 0:
                    new_neighbors.append(arr[i - 1][j])  # top neighbor
                if j != len(arr[i]) - 1:
                    new_neighbors.append(arr[i][j + 1])  # right neighbor
                if i != len(arr) - 1:
                    new_neighbors.append(arr[i + 1][j])  # bottom neighbor
                if j != 0:
                    new_neighbors.append(arr[i][j - 1])  # left neighbor

            else:
                # add neighbors
                new_neighbors = [
                    arr[i - 1][j],  # top neighbor
                    arr[i][j + 1],  # right neighbor
                    arr[i + 1][j],  # bottom neighbor
                    arr[i][j - 1]   # left neighbor
                ]

            neighbors.append({
                "value": value,
                "neighbors": new_neighbors})

    return neighbors
```

Answer (score 3):

My original solution was not correct, @Gnijuohz's is correct.  The following is exactly @Gnijuohz's solution except that the function takes a matrix (`list` of `list`s) as the first argument and the list comprehension has been replaced by nested `for` loops.

```
def neighbors(mat, row, col, radius=1):

    rows, cols = len(mat), len(mat[0])
    out = []

    for i in xrange(row - radius - 1, row + radius):
        row = []
        for j in xrange(col - radius - 1, col + radius):

            if 0 <= i < rows and 0 <= j < cols:
                row.append(mat[i][j])
            else:
                row.append(0)

        out.append(row)

    return out
```

Comment: I tired to pass to a 3d array to this function, but it shows "too many values to unpack, what is the reason? Say, now I change the value of the first row and the first column from 11 to [1, 2, 3]. I think it should work.

Comment: The reason is this line `rows, cols = mat.shape`; it's expecting that `mat.shape` contains two values (i.e. `mat` is a two dimensional array).

Comment: I tested neighbors(mat, 1, 2, 1), it returns an array with shape (3, 5). It is not correct.

Comment: You're right!  I've corrected it, but please accept @Gnijuohz's answer.

Answer (score 1):

I like to use a bounds checking function when doing operations on 2d arrays.  This code doesn't do exactly what you want (It starts from the upper left corner), but it should be enough to boost you along.

```
matrix = [
[11, 21, 31, 41, 51, 61, 71],
[12, 22, 32, 42, 52, 62, 72],
[13, 23, 33, 43, 53, 63, 73],
[14, 24, 34, 44, 54, 64, 74],
[15, 25, 35, 45, 55, 65, 75],
[16, 26, 36, 46, 56, 66, 76],
[17, 27, 37, 47, 57, 67, 77] ]

def in_bounds(matrix, row, col):
    if row < 0 or col < 0:
        return False
    if row > len(matrix)-1 or col > len(matrix)-1:
        return False
    return True

def neighbors(matrix, radius, rowNumber, colNumber):
    for row in range(radius):
        for col in range(radius):
            if in_bounds(matrix, rowNumber+row, colNumber+col):
                print str(matrix[rowNumber+row][colNumber+col]) + " ",
        print ""

neighbors(matrix, 2, 1, 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

This problem is identical to creating a square (or for that matter an n-dimensional cuboid) mask of a given size at a specific position.

The Raster Geometry package provides the means for creating an n-dimensional cuboid via [`raster_geometry.nd_cuboid()`](https://github.com/norok2/raster_geometry/blob/8c112596e2ba5a7fe83060edb345a44f9dcf8bb7/raster_geometry/raster.py#L1544).

A simplified version is reported below:

```py
def neighbors_sq(
        position,
        shape,
        size):
    """Generate mask of given size at given position in an array of given shape."""
    assert len(position) == len(shape)
    n = len(shape)
    semisizes = (size,) * n

    mask = np.zeros(shape, dtype=np.bool_)
    # generate all slicing around the position
    slicing = tuple(
        slice(max(int(x - s), 0), min(int(x + s + 1), d))
        for x, s, d in zip(position, semisizes, shape))
    mask[slicing] = True
    return mask
```

A number of alternate approaches can be devised:

1. Using [`scipy.ndimage.binary_dilation()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.binary_dilation.html#scipy.ndimage.binary_dilation)

```py
import scipy.ndimage


def neighbors_sq_dilate(
        position,
        shape,
        size):
    assert len(position) == len(shape)
    n = len(shape)
    semisizes = (size,) * n

    mask = np.zeros(shape, dtype=np.bool_)
    mask[position] = True
    mask = scipy.ndimage.binary_dilation(
        mask,
        iterations=size,
        structure=scipy.ndimage.generate_binary_structure(n, n))
    return mask
```

2. Using incremental mask applications (this approach is simpler to generalize to non-cuboid neighbors regions, like super-ellipsoids including spheres, see e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46626267/5218354)).

```py
def neighbors_sq_mask(
        position,
        shape,
        size):
    assert len(position) == len(shape)
    n = len(shape)
    semisizes = (size,) * n

    # genereate the grid for the support points
    # centered at the position indicated by position
    grid = [slice(-x0, dim - x0) for x0, dim in zip(position, shape)]
    position = np.ogrid[grid]

    mask = np.ones(shape, dtype=np.bool_)
    # apply consecutive rectangular masks
    for x_i, semisize in zip(position, semisizes):
        mask *= (np.abs(x_i) <= semisize)

    return mask
```

3. Using manual looping (this is limited to 2D for simplicity and cannot be easily written for N-D in a way that Numba is able to accelerate in non-Python mode -- this would probably require strides)

```py
def neighbors_sq_loop(
        position,
        shape,
        size):
    assert len(position) == len(shape)
    n = len(shape)

    mask = np.zeros(shape, dtype=np.bool_)
    for i in range(
            max(int(position[0] - size), 0),
            min(int(position[0] + size + 1), shape[0])):
        for j in range(
                max(int(position[1] - size), 0),
                min(int(position[1] + size + 1), shape[1])):
            mask[i, j] = True

    return mask
```

4. Using Numba-accelerated manual looping (same as above, but accelerated):

```
import numba as nb


neighbors_sq_loop_nb = nb.njit(neighbors_sq_loop)
neighbors_sq_loop_nb.__name__ = "neighbors_sq_loop_nb"
```

---

They all produce the same result:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


funcs = neighbors_sq, neighbors_sq_mask, neighbors_sq_dilate, neighbors_sq_loop, neighbors_sq_loop_nb

fig, axs = plt.subplots(1, len(funcs), squeeze=False, figsize=(4 * len(funcs), 4))

d = 2365
n = 2
shape = (d,) * n
position = (d // 2,) * n
size = (d // 10)

base = neighbors_sq(position, shape, size)
for i, func in enumerate(funcs):
    arr = func(position, shape, size)
    axs[0, i].imshow(arr)
```

[image: plots]

but with different timings, as illustrate below (as always, take timings with a grain of salt):

```py
base = neighbors_sq(position, shape, size)
for func in funcs:
    print(f"{func.__name__:20s}", np.allclose(base, arr), end=" ")
    %timeit -o func(position, shape, size)
# neighbors_sq         True 1000 loops, best of 5: 489 µs per loop
# neighbors_sq_mask    True 1000 loops, best of 5: 1.63 ms per loop
# neighbors_sq_dilate  True 10 loops, best of 5: 99.1 ms per loop
# neighbors_sq_loop    True 10 loops, best of 5: 32.9 ms per loop
# neighbors_sq_loop_nb True 1000 loops, best of 5: 635 µs per loop
```

indicating that the slicing approach is faster by a fair margin (at least with those input sizes, but possibly for most inputs).
The looping approach is not as flexible as the others (requires adaptation for multiple dimensions) and it is not particularly fast, unless it is accelerated with Numba, but it may not be the fastest even with the acceleration.

---

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46626448/5218354) for finding neighbors in a spherical neighborhood instead of a square one.

Answer (score 0):

A little late but I wrote something for finding the neighbours given the radius of search.

```
def nearest_neighout(array, row_idx, col_idx, radius):
    #input
    #array : 2D float64/int : data array to find the nearest neighours from
    #row_idx : int : row index for the center point for which nearest neighour needs to be searched
    #col_idx : int : index for the center point for which nearest neighour needs to be searched
    
    #output
    #returns a list
    #index of the nearest neighours
    #value at that cell
    
    #i iterates over row
    #j iterates over column
    
    above_i = row_idx + radius + 1 #defines the higher limt of row iterator
    if above_i > len(array) - 1: #takes into account the array length to avoid crossing index limits
        above_i = len(array)
    
    below_i = row_idx - radius #defines lower limit
    if below_i < 0: #takes into account the zero index
        below_i = 0
        
        
    above_j = col_idx + radius + 1 #defines the higher limit of column iterator
    if above_j > len(array) - 1: #takes the end index into account
        above_j = len(array)
    
    below_j = col_idx - radius #defines the lower limit of column iterator
    if below_j < 0: #takes zero index into account
        below_j = 0
        
    indices = list()
    for i in range(below_i, above_i):
        for j in range(below_j, above_j):
            indices.append(i, j, array[i,j])
    
    return indices
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote the following code making use of the **in_bounds** function from Ben Doan`s answer. It should return the expected results.

```
import numpy as np

matrix = [
[11, 21, 31, 41, 51, 61, 71],
[12, 22, 32, 42, 52, 62, 72],
[13, 23, 33, 43, 53, 63, 73],
[14, 24, 34, 44, 54, 64, 74],
[15, 25, 35, 45, 55, 65, 75],
[16, 26, 36, 46, 56, 66, 76],
[17, 27, 37, 47, 57, 67, 77] ]

def in_bounds(matrix, row, col):
    if row < 0 or col < 0:
        return False
    if row > len(matrix)-1 or col > len(matrix[0])-1:
        return False
    return True

def neighbourIndexList(row, col, radius):
    result = []
    for i in range(- radius, radius+1):
        for j in range(- radius, radius+1):
            result.append([row + i, col + j])
    return result

def neighborValues(matrix, radius, rowNumber, colNumber):
    rowNumber = rowNumber - 1
    colNumber = colNumber - 1
    neighbours = neighbourIndexList(rowNumber, colNumber, radius)
    dim = radius *2 + 1
    neighboursVal = []
    if in_bounds(matrix, rowNumber, colNumber) == False:
        return neighboursVal
    else:
        for neighbour in neighbours:
            if in_bounds(matrix, neighbour[0], neighbour[1]):
                neighboursVal.append(matrix[neighbour[0]][neighbour[1]])
            else:
                neighboursVal.append(0)
    neighboursVal = np.asarray(neighboursVal)
    y = np.expand_dims(neighboursVal, axis=0)
    result = np.reshape(y, (dim, dim))
    return result

neighbourList = neighborValues(matrix, 2, 3, 3)
print(neighbourList)
```