# How to create a sphere inside an ndarray?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a ndarray of size `32x32x32`. I want to create a sphere inside the array with the center at `(x,y)` and a radius of 4 pixels. The value of the sphere is 1 while value of the array is 0. How can this be done in python?

This is the code to generate the array:

```
import numpy as np
A = np.zeros((32,32,32))
print (A)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "cube (circle)"? Cubes aren't circles.

Comment: Do you want a circle (2D) or a sphere (3D)?

Comment: Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [On topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [... the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.  For instance, give an example of what you want, and post your coding attempt.

Comment: Sorry about that. It is sphere, sorry for my poor English

Comment: No worries, Moon. It's fine. =) I was just clarifying.

Comment: Surely you will need a 3-d position for the centre, like `(x,y,z)`?

Comment: How about trying something? You only need to iterate over the 8x8x8 cube centred on (x,y,z) rather than the whole array...

Answer (score 7):

Very good question. You can try the following code. In the below mentioned code `AA` is the matrix that you want. =)

```
import numpy as np
from copy import deepcopy

''' size : size of original 3D numpy matrix A.
    radius : radius of circle inside A which will be filled with ones. 
'''
size, radius = 5, 2

''' A : numpy.ndarray of shape size*size*size. '''
A = np.zeros((size,size, size)) 

''' AA : copy of A (you don't want the original copy of A to be overwritten.) '''
AA = deepcopy(A) 

''' (x0, y0, z0) : coordinates of center of circle inside A. '''
x0, y0, z0 = int(np.floor(A.shape[0]/2)), \
        int(np.floor(A.shape[1]/2)), int(np.floor(A.shape[2]/2))


for x in range(x0-radius, x0+radius+1):
    for y in range(y0-radius, y0+radius+1):
        for z in range(z0-radius, z0+radius+1):
            ''' deb: measures how far a coordinate in A is far from the center. 
                    deb>=0: inside the sphere.
                    deb<0: outside the sphere.'''   
            deb = radius - abs(x0-x) - abs(y0-y) - abs(z0-z) 
            if (deb)>=0: AA[x,y,z] = 1
```

Following is an example of the output for `size=5` and `radius=2` (a sphere of radius `2` pixels inside a numpy array of shape `5*5*5`):

```
[[[0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 1. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]

 [[0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 1. 0. 0.]
  [0. 1. 1. 1. 0.]
  [0. 0. 1. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]

 [[0. 0. 1. 0. 0.]
  [0. 1. 1. 1. 0.]
  [1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]
  [0. 1. 1. 1. 0.]
  [0. 0. 1. 0. 0.]]

 [[0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 1. 0. 0.]
  [0. 1. 1. 1. 0.]
  [0. 0. 1. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]

 [[0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 1. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]]
```

I haven't printed the output for the size and radius that you had asked for (`size=32` and `radius=4`), as the output will be very long.

Comment: Please notice that this generates a square, not a sphere, as the Manhattan distance (l1 norm) is used in `deb = radius - abs(x0-x) - abs(y0-y) - abs(z0-z)` . The code works, if you change this line of code to: `deb = radius - ((x0-x)**2 + (y0-y)**2 + (z0-z)**2)**0.5 `, which uses the Euclidean distance (l2 norm).

Answer (score 4):

Since array indexes only have a certain level of specificity (i.e. you can only subdivide down to the width, in this case 32), there's no one perfect way to represent a sphere in an array. Instead, we can treat each array index as a space of cubic area, where the `[x][y][z]` indices of the index represent the the cubic area's center coordinates. To create the sphere, we evaluate whether the sphere's presence in that area of space meets certain criteria.

We start with the equation for a sphere. From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sphere):

> In analytic geometry, a sphere with center (*x0*, *y0*, *z0*) and radius *r* is the locus of all points (*x*, *y*, *z*) such that
>
> (*x* - *x0*)^2 + (*y* - *y0*)^2 + (*z* - *z0*)^2 <= *r*^2.

For an array of dimensions N, the center will have the coordinate (N - 1) / 2 for all dimensions. (because for an even-numbered dimension, the center should be between the two center points, and for an odd-numbered dimension, the center should be an integer.) The magnitude of the radius can vary depending on where you decide the boundaries of the sphere relative to our imagined cubic array representation; re-reading the question, I notice you already gave the desired radius: 4.

There are two evaluation criteria I can think of:

## Simple approach

In this approach, we will simply use a test of whether the array index's cubic area's center lies within the circle equation.

You can see [Siddharth Satpathy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53328308/8117067) for some code using this approach.

## Sophisticated approach

Ideally for me, the equation would decide whether an index lies within the sphere by assessing whether the proportion of sphere for that cubic area is greater than 50%. However, this approach unfortunately goes beyond my current working mathematical knowledge.

---

In regards to a discussion I had in the comments, neither approach is better than the other since they represent different perspectives: I personally imagine the array as being actually representative of the cubic area for each index, while others may imagine the indexes being the center points of these cubic areas.

Comment: ".. whether the proportion of sphere for that cubic area is greater than 50%." An interesting idea. If you consider each data point a *cube*, then you can test if its center is inside the sphere. That ought to do it – at least for spheres larger than a single cube.

Comment: @usr2564301 The center of a point's cube being inside the sphere doesn't guarantee that the area occupied inside that cube is greater than 50%. While the first approach is a good approximation, I think a 50% comparison is more satisfying in certain ways. But I think the difference lies in perspective of what the array indexes represent: cubic area measurements, or the center points of these cubic areas. Your argument seems to be based on the array indexes being the centers' coordinates, while I am thinking of them as proportions of cubic area.

Answer (score 4):

Nothing above worked for me so there is my attempt:

```py
def create_bin_sphere(arr_size, center, r):
    coords = np.ogrid[:arr_size[0], :arr_size[1], :arr_size[2]]
    distance = np.sqrt((coords[0] - center[0])**2 + (coords[1]-center[1])**2 + (coords[2]-center[2])**2) 
    return 1*(distance <= r)
```

where:

- arr_size is a tuple with numpy array shape
- center is a tuple with sphere center coords
- r is a radius of the sphere

Example:

```py
arr_size = (30,30,30)
sphere_center = (15,15,15)
r=10
sphere = create_bin_sphere(arr_size,sphere_center, r)

#Plot the result
fig =plt.figure(figsize=(6,6))
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
ax.voxels(sphere, facecolors=colors, edgecolor='k')
plt.show()
```

[Vizualization rezult](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IFit9.png)

Answer (score 2):

Eventhough it's a little late - I recently faced the same problem and solved it somewhat like the solution supposed by Mstaino. Also, Mstainos solution doesn't work for asymetricly sized array's, because shapes will not match when calculating the distance.

So here's my approach in 3D which produces a sphere in the center of the array. :

```
# define array size and sphere radius
size = [size_x, size_y, size_z]
radius = sphere_radius

# compute center index of array
center = [int(size[0]/2), int(size[1]/2), int(size[2]/2)]

# create index grid for array
ind_0, ind_1, ind_2 = np.indices((size[0], size[1], size[2]))

# calculate "distance" of indices to center index
distance = ((ind_0 - center[0])**2 + (ind_1 - center[1])**2 + (ind_2 - center[2])**2)**.5

# create output
output = np.ones(shape = (size[0], size[1], size[2])) * (distance <= radius)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a combination of indexing, distance calculation and masking (all with `numpy`):

```
import numpy as np
center = (31/2, 31/2, 31/2)  # if it is centered
size = (32, 32, 32)
max_dist = 4
distance = np.linalg.norm(np.subtract(np.indices(size).T, np.asarray(center)), axis=2)
#print(distance)
mask = np.ones(size) * (distance < max_dist)
print(mask)
```

`np.indices` creates an index in the form `[[[(i, j, k)]]]`, `np.substract` calculates the vector difference to your center, and `np.linalg.norm` calculates the vector norm. The rest is just using a mask operation on the distance array.

Does that work?

EDIT: an example with (3,3,3) for clarity purposes

```
center = (1, 1, 1)
size = (3, 3, 3)
distance = np.linalg.norm(np.subtract(np.indices(size).T,np.asarray(center)), axis=len(center))
mask = np.ones(size) * (distance<=1)
print(mask)

>>[[[0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 1. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0.]]

 [[0. 1. 0.]
  [1. 1. 1.]
  [0. 1. 0.]]

 [[0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 1. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0.]]]
```