# How can I correctly classify the number of positive (bright color) circles and negative (dark color) circles in the image

Tags: python, opencv, detection, hough-transform

Long post - please bear with me.

For a better understanding of what the goal is and what I have done so far, I have posted the code. Please let me know if any further information is required.

I have an image (as shown) and **the goal is to correctly classify the number of positive (blue) and negative (purple) circles**. *I do not care about the semi-circles in the image*. As shown in the image, there are 29 circles (excluding the semi circles) in which there 7 positive ones. But my code detects only 1 positive. Here is what I have done so far:

[image: input_image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image
import math
import cv2.cv as cv

# --------Read Images--------------------------

I = cv2.imread('input_image.jpg')

# -----------Apply Contrast---------------------

lab = cv2.cvtColor(I, cv2.COLOR_BGR2LAB)  # Converting image to LAB Color model
l, a, b = cv2.split(lab)  # Splitting the LAB image to different channels

clahe = cv2.createCLAHE(clipLimit=3.0, tileGridSize=(8, 8))  # Applying CLAHE to L-channel
cl = clahe.apply(l)

limg = cv2.merge((cl, a, b))  # Merge the CLAHE enhanced L-channel with the a and b channel

localContrast = cv2.cvtColor(limg, cv2.COLOR_LAB2BGR)  # Converting image from LAB Color model to RGB model

print("Local Contrast shape is", localContrast.shape)
print("Local Contrast shape is", type(localContrast))

cv2.imwrite('./Output/localContrast.jpg', localContrast)

# -------------Find Circles -----------------------

input_img = cv2.imread('./Output/localContrast.jpg')  # Read Contrast Image

gray_img = cv2.cvtColor(input_img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
blur_img = cv2.medianBlur(gray_img, 7)

circles = cv2.HoughCircles(blur_img, cv.CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT, dp=1, minDist=20, param1=50, param2=30, minRadius=5,
                           maxRadius=36)

circles = np.uint16(np.around(circles))

no_of_circles = 0 

radii = []
cx= []
cy = []

if circles is not None:

    # convert the (x, y) coordinates and radius of the circles to integers

    circles = np.round(circles[0, :]).astype("int")
    no_of_circles = len(circles)

    # loop over the (x, y) coordinates and radius of the circles

    for (x,y,r) in circles:

        radii.append(r)
        cx.append(x)
        cy.append(y)
        centers = [cx, cy]

        # draw the circle in the output image, then draw a rectangle
        # corresponding to the center of the circle

        cv2.circle(input_img, (x, y), r, (0, 0, 255), 2)
cv2.imwrite('/home/vr1019/Notebook/Output/circle_img.jpg', input_img) 
print ('no of circles',no_of_circles)
```

The output is as shown in the image below: ('no of circles', 30)

[image: circle_detected]

Next, I calculated the intensity of each circle by taking the top 10 % of the pixel value (this is how I need to calculate the intensity). ***The idea is taken from [createCirclesMask.m](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/47905-createcirclesmask-m)***

```
def createCircleMask(localContrast, centers, radii):

      radii = np.reshape(radii, (len(radii),1))

      centers = np.asarray(centers)
      centers = np.transpose(centers)

      xdim = localContrast.shape[0]
      ydim = localContrast.shape[1]

      x = np.arange(0, xdim)
      y = np.arange(0, ydim)

      x = np.reshape(x, (1, len(x)))
      y = np.reshape(y, (1, len(y)))

     [xx,yy]= np.meshgrid(y, x)


      xc = centers[:,0]
      xc = np.reshape(xc, (len(xc),1))

      yc = centers[:,1]
      yc = np.reshape(yc, (len(yc),1))
      circle_intensity = []
      for ii in range(len(radii)):
           r_square = np.square(radii)
           var1= (np.square(y-xc[ii,0]))
           var2 = np.square(np.transpose(x)-yc[ii,0])
           cx,cy = np.where((var1 + var2)<r_square[ii])
           i1 =[]
           i2 =[]
           i3 =[]

           npixel = cx.shape[0]

           for j in range(npixel):

               i1.append(localContrast[cx[j],cy[j],0]);
               localContrast[cx[j],cy[j],0] = 0;

               i2.append(localContrast[cx[j],cy[j],1]);
               localContrast[cx[j],cy[j],1] = 0;

               i3.append(localContrast[cx[j],cy[j],2]);
               localContrast[cx[j],cy[j],2] = 0;

           s1= sorted(i1, reverse = True)
           s2=sorted(i2, reverse = True)
           s3=sorted(i3, reverse = True)

           # top 10 percent intensity

           m1 = np.asarray(s1[0:np.int(round(abs(len(s1)*0.1)))])
           m2 = np.asarray(s1[0:np.int(round(abs(len(s2)*0.1)))])
           m3 = np.asarray(s1[0:np.int(round(abs(len(s3)*0.1)))])

           m = np.mean((m1+m2+m3)/3)

           circle_intensity.append(m)

      print("The len of circle_intensty is", len(circle_intensity))

      return circle_intensity
```

and then plotting a histogram of circle_intensity gives:

[image: histogram of circle_intensity]

I don't know what I am doing wrong. Could anyone help me out here? I looked online for the solution (like pyimagesearch or stackoverflow etc), but couldn't find what I was looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You got almost every right, if you are not worried about one mis-classified blob, the partial blobs not being detected at all, and the (apparently) inaccurate size for some of the blobs.

The last problem to solve is to get a sensible threshold between the bright and the dark blobs. One way to do so is to use an adaptive threshold, like e.g. the [Otsu's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Otsu%27s_method) or others.

Have a look here for more [threshold methods](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/xx_applications/plot_thresholding.html) from scikit-learn.

*EDIT: Updated to better match what you were asking.*

---

Briefly, compared to your code, I have done the following modifications:

- Put all the code inside functions (it helps me reason better)
- I have defined a contrast enhancement function, but it is not used in the code (because I was getting worse results.)
- define a function that generates masks associated to the circles (note that this function would by available, with slightly different parameters, in [PyMRT](https://bitbucket.org/norok2/pymrt) - **Disclaimer**: I am the main author of it.)
- threshold the circles using the masks from above and the Otsu method for determining the optimal threshold value

(minor note: I saved the input image as `blobs.jpg`).

This is how I would have done it, but I am sure that there is room for improving its robustness by tweaking the parameters.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from skimage.filters import threshold_otsu


# based on: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46626267/how-to-generate-a-sphere-in-3d-numpy-array/46626448#46626448
def circle(shape, radius, position):
    semisizes = (radius,) * 2
    grid = [slice(-x0, dim - x0) for x0, dim in zip(position, shape)]
    position = np.ogrid[grid]
    arr = np.zeros(shape, dtype=float)
    for x_i, semisize in zip(position, semisizes):
        arr += (np.abs(x_i / semisize) ** 2)
    return arr <= 1.0


def enhance_contrast(
        in_img,
        save_filepath=None):
    """Enhance contrast."""
    lab_img = cv2.cvtColor(in_img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2LAB)  
    l_ch, a_ch, b_ch = cv2.split(lab_img)
    # Applying CLAHE to L-channel
    clahe_filter = cv2.createCLAHE(clipLimit=3.0, tileGridSize=(8, 8))
    l_ch = clahe_filter.apply(l_ch)
    out_img = cv2.merge((l_ch, a_ch, b_ch))
    out_img = cv2.cvtColor(out_img, cv2.COLOR_LAB2BGR)
    if save_filepath:
        cv2.imwrite(save_filepath, out_img)
    return out_img


def find_circles(
        in_filepath,
        out_filepath='circles_{in_filepath}',
        enh_filepath='enh_{in_filepath}',
        hough_circles_kws=(
            ('dp', 1), ('minDist', 15), ('param1', 30), ('param2', 30),
            ('minRadius', 5), ('maxRadius', 25)),
        verbose=True):
    """Find circles in image."""
    out_filepath = out_filepath.format(**locals())
    enh_filepath = enh_filepath.format(**locals())
    hough_circles_kws = dict(hough_circles_kws) if hough_circles_kws else {}

    in_img = cv2.imread(in_filepath)
    lab_img = cv2.cvtColor(in_img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2LAB)
    l_ch, a_ch, b_ch = cv2.split(lab_img)
    blur_l_ch = cv2.medianBlur(l_ch, 1)
    circles = cv2.HoughCircles(blur_l_ch, cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT, **hough_circles_kws)
    if circles is not None:
        values_img = l_ch
        # compute means
        if verbose:
            print('Image size: ', values_img.shape)
        circles = np.squeeze(circles)
        values = []
        for x0, y0, r in circles:
            mask = circle(values_img.shape, r, (y0, x0))
            values.append(np.percentile(values_img[mask], 90))
        circles = np.concatenate((circles, np.array(values).reshape(-1, 1)), -1)
        threshold = threshold_otsu(np.array(values))
        if verbose:
            print('Threshold: ', threshold)
        # plot circles
        for x0, y0, r, mean in circles:
            if mean > threshold:
                # good circles in green
                cv2.circle(in_img, (int(x0), int(y0)), int(r), (0, 255, 0), 2)
            else:
                # bad circles in red
                cv2.circle(in_img, (int(x0), int(y0)), int(r), (0, 0, 255), 2)
        if verbose:
            print('Circles:')
            print(circles)
            print('Num Circles: ', circles.shape[0])
            print('Good Circles: ', np.sum(values > threshold))
    if out_filepath:
        cv2.imwrite(out_filepath.format(**locals()), in_img)
    return out_filepath, circles, threshold


out_filepath, circles, threshold = find_circles('blobs.jpg')
```

This would generate the following output:

```
Image size:  (230, 294)
Threshold:  96.1328125
Circles:
[[ 36.5        108.5         21.10000038 155.5       ]
 [170.5        124.5         24.39999962 170.        ]
 [ 43.5        156.5         21.10000038 156.5       ]
 [ 33.5         57.5         22.20000076 190.        ]
 [101.5         40.5         19.89999962  90.        ]
 [ 75.5         78.5         18.79999924  88.        ]
 [254.5        171.5         16.60000038  82.        ]
 [138.5         52.5         15.39999962  90.        ]
 [123.5        148.5         14.39999962  90.        ]
 [ 42.5        199.5         15.39999962 174.        ]
 [138.5         15.5         14.10000038  88.        ]
 [ 86.5        176.5         15.39999962  90.        ]
 [256.5         23.5         15.5        146.        ]
 [211.5        140.5         14.39999962  87.        ]
 [132.5        193.5         13.19999981  90.1       ]
 [174.5         35.5          9.60000038  93.        ]
 [ 81.5        129.5         11.          93.        ]
 [223.5         54.5          9.60000038  87.        ]
 [177.5         75.5         13.19999981 146.        ]
 [214.5        195.5         11.          90.        ]
 [259.5        126.5          9.60000038  90.        ]
 [ 62.5         22.5         11.          96.        ]
 [220.5         98.5          9.60000038  89.        ]
 [263.5         77.5         12.10000038  84.1       ]
 [116.5        101.5          9.60000038  92.        ]
 [170.5        177.5         11.          91.        ]
 [251.5        215.5         11.          91.        ]
 [167.5        215.5         11.          87.        ]
 [214.5         14.5          9.60000038  92.        ]]
Num Circles:  29
Good Circles:  7
```

and the corresponding image:

[image: circles_blobs.jpg]

(and of course you can adapt the code above to better fit your needs).

*EDIT: Included some code and figures.*

It is also possible to plot a barchart of good/bad results:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

values = circles[:, -1]
data = [np.sum(values <= threshold), np.sum(values > threshold)]

labels = ['Bad', 'Good']
colors = ['red', 'green']

ax.bar(labels, data, color=colors)
plt.show()
```

[image: circles_good_bad]

Or to plot a complete histogram, e.g.:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

hist, edges = np.histogram(values, bins=40)
widths = (edges[1:] - edges[:-1])
ax.bar(edges[:-1] + widths / 2, hist, widths)  # plots the histogram
ax.axvline(x=threshold, color='black')  # plots the threshold (optional)
plt.show()
```

[image: circles_histogram]

**EDIT: Included additional barplot and histogram**

Comment: Hello, Thank you for your reply. So, you mean that I should first put the threshold and then do the createCircleMask function or before circle detection?

Comment: No, I mean that once the circles are found, and their mean (or otherwise characteristic) intensity is computed, you would need a threshold (like Otsu's) for separating the positive from the negatives.

Comment: I have included some code and the corresponding output

Comment: Because you left so fast you missed the chance to learn. This is what you're looking for: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @norok2: This is perfect! Thank you very much for your help. I went through the code and tried to understand how does the code works. I have got a couple of questions (please forgive if some of them are silly. I am still a beginner)

1. Is there a need of def enhance_contrast function? Since it is not used anywhere in the code
2. Why do we need np.percentile?
3. How to get the same result i.e. Good_circles = 7 and Bad_circles = 22 in histogram form?
4. What is the need of "if verbose:"? Isn't it possible to print without using if statement?

Once again, Thank you very much!

Comment: @Riya208 No problem. (1) No there is no need for it, I just included because you had it in your code; (2) `np.percentile()` implements "taking the top 10% of the pixel value" as you indicated (see its docs for more info); (3) I am not sure I am understanding the `histogram` question.. if you want to plot bars you could use e.g. [matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/examples/api/barchart_demo.html); (4) the `verbose` bit is there only because you may not want to print every time you use it. Finally, you may want to upvote / accept the answer. :-)

Comment: @norok2: What I mean is I want the distribution of bad circles and the good circles. **What (or how) should be the input data for matplotlib.pyplot.hist or np.histogram?** Because I cannot give _np.sum(values > threshold_ as my input because (1) it gives me an error (2) it will give me the distribution of only good circles and not bad circles. I tried _circles_ as input, but that also gives me error because it is 29*4 matrix and moreover circles won't give me a ditribution since good circles are obtained by putting the threshold on values (i.e. np.sum(values > threshold)).

Comment: @Riya208: I think what you want is actually a barplot of good/bad results. But I have included also a proper histogram of the values (I want to only use the `values` and not the `circles`). Note that I also modified the function to return also `circles` and `threshold`.

Comment: @norok2 Thank you very much! I wish I could do more than upvote and accepting the answer!

Comment: @norok2 I was just wondering why the positive circles don't have Gaussian distribution? Is it because the data point above the positive values is not scaled properly? Clearly, the negative circles (i.e. value below threshold) have Gaussian distribution. Because I thought both (positives and the negatives) should have Gaussian distribution

Comment: @Riya208: It's a bit of topic... anyway I'll try to repy: (1) the negative look to me as they have a Poisson distribution; (2) the are too few positive to infer a a distribution by eye; (3) the underlying distribution will depend in general on the physics behind the process you observe, and I do not know how the image was generated, so it's hard to say what to expect.