# How to do unit testing on Image as input and output in python?

Tags: python, unit-testing, opencv, oop, hough-transform

I am doing unit testing on object detection [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54576667/how-can-i-correctly-classify-the-number-of-positive-bright-color-circles-and-n) (accepted answer) in Python. I know that in unit testing, we basically put in test parameters to functions we have defined in our program and we enter the expected result. If the expected result is output, we get OK, otherwise, we will get an error.

So my problem is that my **input** is the **Image** and my **output** is the also an image (i.e. **object detected in the image**) and later on, the result is represented using the bar chart and the histogram with slider. **How can I do unit testing on such data?**

So far, this is what I have tried (This [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54576667/how-can-i-correctly-classify-the-number-of-positive-bright-color-circles-and-n) is saved as cirCode)

```
from unittest import TestCase

import unittest
from unittest import TestCase
import cirCode

class TestFind_circles(TestCase):

        def setUp(self):
            pass

        def tearDown(self):
            pass

        #def test_circle(self):
         #   self.fail()

        def test_find_circles(self):

            Negative_circles, Positive_circles, out_filepath, circles, threshold = cirCode.find_circles('blobs.jpg')

            self.assertEqual(Negative_circles, 20)
            self.assertEqual(Positive_circles, 8)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Now, I do not know how to test **def circle** function. Also, I am not sure if it is a correct way to test **find_circles** function.

Do you guys have any better idea to do the unit test on this [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54576667/how-can-i-correctly-classify-the-number-of-positive-bright-color-circles-and-n) and also how can I proceed with the unit test on the *circle* function?

Comment: Does it return bitmap? Would it be the same for known input? If so, you can at least do binary comparison of the returned bitmap vs expected.

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski It returns the threshold value from the Otsu method, circles which give information on the coordinates of the circle centre along with the radius and the mean RGB value, the output file name and the number of Negative circles and Positive circles. So, no, it doesn't return the bitmap. But doing a binary comparison on a large image would be difficult, isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you are asking, I assume you are asking for unit testing method for opencv function and variables.

How about following opencv python test sample? They did a similar work that you are trying to do already. They have dozens of sample test case.

https://github.com/opencv/opencv/tree/master/modules/python/test

e.g

```
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np
import sys
from numpy import pi, sin, cos

from tests_common import NewOpenCVTests

def circleApproximation(circle):

    nPoints = 30
    dPhi = 2*pi / nPoints
    contour = []
    for i in range(nPoints):
        contour.append(([circle[0] + circle[2]*cos(i*dPhi),
            circle[1] + circle[2]*sin(i*dPhi)]))

    return np.array(contour).astype(int)
```

Comment: I want to do unit testing of the functions in the code (the link). I have mentioned it in the question "... how to test def circle function. Also, I am not sure if it is a correct way to test find_circles function.". Thanks for the link. I will definitely check it out :) . I hope it gives me a better perspective on how to proceed further.