# Python Generating 3D sphere in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, shapes, numpy-ndarray

So currently I've made a numpy 3D array of zeros, but I am trying to create a bunch of different spheres that can be represented by a numpy array.  However, I am stuck on how to actually do that.  How would I be able to create a numpy array representing a sphere if I had a specified center and a specified radius?

Comment: What do you mean by *represent*? A sphere can be uniquely represented by a center and radius. That's one representation. What do you mean when you say you want to represent it as a numpy array?

Comment: As in represent a sphere through a numpy array.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to generate a sphere in 3D Numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46626267/how-to-generate-a-sphere-in-3d-numpy-array)

Answer (score 5):

This is certainly not standard, but I would use [spherical coordinate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system)

```
def create_sphere(cx,cy,cz, r, resolution=360):
    '''
    create sphere with center (cx, cy, cz) and radius r
    '''
    phi = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 2*resolution)
    theta = np.linspace(0, np.pi, resolution)

    theta, phi = np.meshgrid(theta, phi)

    r_xy = r*np.sin(theta)
    x = cx + np.cos(phi) * r_xy
    y = cy + np.sin(phi) * r_xy
    z = cz + r * np.cos(theta)

    return np.stack([x,y,z])
```