# Raster geometry sphere not working as expected

Tags: python, numpy, mask, shapes

I'm trying to use raster geometry to make a sphere-shaped mask (found in [How to generate a sphere in 3D Numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46626267/how-to-generate-a-sphere-in-3d-numpy-array/46626448?noredirect=1#comment128980904_46626448) made by user @norok2). Code is as following:

```
import raster_geometry as rg
import numpy as np

sphere_mask = rg.sphere((224, 224, 160), 15,(112,112,80)) #rg.sphere takes(shape,radius,midpoint)
sphere_mask = sphere_mask.astype(np.int_) 

print(np.sum(sphere_mask))
```

When I print the sum of the sphere mask, it gives 0 so no sphere was created.
Modifying the code to not include the midpoint however works fine:

```
import raster_geometry as rg
import numpy as np

sphere_mask = rg.sphere((224, 224, 160), 15) #rg.sphere takes(shape,radius,midpoint)
sphere_mask = sphere_mask.astype(np.int_) 

print(np.sum(sphere_mask))
```

I've adapted the midpoint to be contained well within the shape of the image.
I'm not sure what's going wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `position` parameter of `rg.sphere()` is a `float` or `(float, float, float)` which indicates the position of the center of the sphere in relative units, originating from its lowest edge.

This means that a value of `0.5` will translate into the middle of the shape.
If a single value is provided, this is propagated in all dimensions, otherwise a value for each dimension must be provided.

```py
import numpy as np
import raster_geometry as rg


m0 = rg.sphere((224, 224, 160), 15).astype(np.int_)
m1 = rg.sphere((224, 224, 160), 15, 0.5).astype(np.int_)
m2 = rg.sphere((224, 224, 160), 15, (0.5, 0.5, 0.5)).astype(np.int_)


print(np.sum(m0) > 0, np.allclose(m0, m1), np.allclose(m0, m2))
# True True True
```

---

If you provide a value outside of the `(0.0, 1.0)` interval, this will place the center outside of the shape, and unless the radius is large enough, it will produce an empty mask.

---

If you want to specify absolute values, you should use the more powerful `rg.nd_superellipsoid()` (which is what `rg.sphere()` uses internally anyway) where you can control how the position parameter is interpreted via the `rel_position` parameter.

Comment: Thank you so much! rg.nd_superellipsoid() works like a charm.