# how to get all the position of pixels around a pixel

Tags: python, loops, pixel

So I'm trying to get the positions of pixels that surround a pixel :
for example :

```
0 0 0 0
x x x 0
x 1 x 0
x x x 0
```

I need to get the positions of all those Xs.
The problem for me isn't the general case I can do a double-loop to get them, the problem is the conditions. Because what came to my mind is to manually code every case, but it isn't efficient and takes too many lines.
Therefore, I'm asking if there is an easier way to do so
I can program it manually by doing several if statement and assign their values to an array

Here is what i wrote for the moment it takes to many lines and isn't efficient

```
def cond_i_zero(pos_array,i,j):
    pos_array[0] = i
    pos_array[1] = j-1
    pos_array[2] = i
    pos_array[3] = j+1
    pos_array[4] = i+1
    pos_array[5] = j-1
    pos_array[6] = i+1
    pos_array[7] = j
    pos_array[8] = i+1
    pos_array[9] = j+1
    return pos_array

def cond_j_zero(pos_array,i,j):
    pos_array[0] = i-1
    pos_array[1] = j
    pos_array[2] = i-1
    pos_array[3] = j+1
    pos_array[4] = i
    pos_array[5] = j+1
    pos_array[6] = i+1
    pos_array[7] = j
    pos_array[8] = i+1
    pos_array[9] = j+1      
    return pos_array

"""
i,j : represent the position of the pixel that is equivalent to 1 in the
      example above
total_img_nb : 16 for the example

output expected : array of positions so for example since the maximum of pixels that suround a pixel is 8 the output will be an array of size 16
where every pair number represent the i(row) pos and every odd number represent the j (columns) pos
""" 
def pos_in_array(total_imgs_nb,i,j):
    
    x = 2
    y = 2
    size = int(math.sqrt(total_imgs_nb))-1
    if ( i == 0 ):
        x = 1
    if ( j == 0 ):
        y = 1
    if ( i == size ):
        x = size - 1
    if  ( j == size ):
        y = size - 1

    pos_array = np.zeros(( total_imgs_nb ))
    pos_array += 999

    if((i==0 and j == 0) or (i==size and j == size)):
        pos_array[0] = i
        pos_array[1] = y
        pos_array[2] = x
        pos_array[3] = j
        pos_array[4] = x
        pos_array[5] = y
    elif (i==0):
        pos_array=cond_i_zero(pos_array,i,j)
    elif (j==0):
        pos_array=cond_j_zero(pos_array,i,j)
    elif (i==size):
        pos_array[0] = i
        pos_array[1] = y
        pos_array[2] = x
        pos_array[3] = j
        pos_array[4] = x
        pos_array[5] = y
        pos_array[6] = y
        pos_array[7] = y
        pos_array[8] = y
        pos_array[9] = y
    else:
        count = 0
        for w in range(i-1,i+2):
                for v in range(j-1,j+2):
                        pos_array[count] = w    
                        count = count +1
                        pos_array[count] = v
                        count = count +1
    
    return pos_array
```

```
def main():
   pos_array = pos_in_array(16,1,1)

# this usually return 
[0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 2. 1. 0. 1. 2. 2. 0. 2. 1. 2. 2.]
```

Comment: please share your attempt [mcve]

Comment: One (probably more memory expensive than needed, but vectorized) way of doing this is to generate a mask of the pixel you are interested, dilate it and then use it as a mask of the original array.

Comment: @norok2 the problem is that this the first part of my program and my program already takes a long time to execute and parallelizing it is already causing problems and the method that you proposed will slow and cause more problems for me

Comment: Not sure how this is related to my comment. Anyway, I welcome that you added some code to your question, but perhaps you could also provide some minimal input/output/expected output to beef it up.

Comment: @norok2 did what I add above the function pos_in_array answer your suggestion ?

Comment: Not really, I was thinking more along the line of providing some code using the function.

Comment: @norok2  what about now ? in the main at the end

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/22550933/2681662

Comment: yes, this is perfect thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how i did it .
first i get the number of neighbours for the pixel
then i create a 1-D array of double the size of the neighbours and then i bound the loop and add the position to the array .

```
        size = int(math.sqrt(nb_total))
        if((i==0 and (j ==0 or j==size-1))or (i==size-1  and (j == size -1 or j==0))):
            neighbors = 3
        elif(i==0 or j==0 or i==size-1 or j==size-1):
            neighbors = 5
        else:
            neighbors = 8

    array_pos = np.zeros((neighbors*2))
    count = 0
    for x in range(size):
        for y in range(size):
            if(x == i and y == j ):
                continue
            if((x < i+2 and y <j+2)and (x> i-2 and y > j-2 )):
                array_pos[count] = x
                count = count + 1
                array_pos[count] = y
                count = count + 1
                if(count == neighbors*2):
                    break
        if(count == neighbors*2):
                break
    return array_pos
```